# Create a function from code

Tags: swift, avaudioplayer

How do I create a function from this code in swift3?

I have a button which is pressed then plays this sound "push"

How can it be simplified when there are lots of buttons? I don't want to add all codes to every button.

```
 var myAudio = AVAudioPlayer()
// Add sound
        do {
            try myAudio = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath:
                Bundle.main.path(forResource: "push", ofType: "mp3")!) as URL)
        } catch {
            NSLog("No file!")

        }
//call the sound
myAudio.play()
```

I made this change

```
func play(name : String){

        do {
            try myAudio = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: NSURL(fileURLWithPath:
                Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: "mp3")!) as URL)

        } catch {
            NSLog("No file!")

        }


    }

    @IBAction func buttonFirst(_ sender: UIButton) {

        play(name: "push")
        myAudio.play()

    }

    @IBAction func buttonSecond(_ sender: UIButton) {
        play(name: "second")
        myAudio.play()
    }
```

I got this output:
2017-07-25 16:13:23.270349+0100 sound[1728:933024] [aqme] 254: AQDefaultDevice (173): skipping input stream 0 0 0x0

Is that a problem?

Comment: How did you create your buttons, from code or from IB?

Comment: I created from IB (IBaction)

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot the prepare

```
    var audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer()
    let sound = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "sound", ofType: "mp3")!)

    try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback)
    try! AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setActive(true)

    try! audioPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: sound)
    audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
    audioPlayer.play()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it in the following way

```
    var myAudio : AVAudioPlayer?

func playSound(){
    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "push", ofType:"mp3")!
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

    do {
        let sound = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        self.myAudio = sound
        sound.numberOfLoops = 1
        sound.prepareToPlay()
        sound.play()
    } catch {
        print("error loading file")
        // couldn't load file :(
    }
}
```

Furthermore you can use [SwiftySound](https://github.com/adamcichy/SwiftySound) that lets you play sounds easily in Swift 3.
for example

```
Sound.play(file: "push.mp3")
```